# error while connecting to vertica database via pdo

Tags: php, pdo, vertica

I am getting problem in connecting vertica database with php using pdo it's throwing me error

> [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified' SQLSTATE SQLSTATE[IM002]

My connection string is as follows :-

```
$conn = new PDO('odbc:DRIVER={SOURCENAME};Server=localhost;Database=dashboard', "yogesh", "");
```

The same dsn works with isql utility but not with pdo .

Comment: This isn't really enough information to help here. Can you post the contents of your odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini?

Comment: my odbc.ini consist :-[ODBC Data Sources]
dashboard = MyODBC VERTICA DSN

[dashboard]
Driver = /opt/vertica/lib64/libverticaodbc.so.6.0.1
Description = Vertica test instance
ServerName = localhost
UserName = yogesh
Database = dashboard
Password = ''
Port = 5433

[Driver]
ODBCInstLib =/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.so.1
ErrorMessagesPath = /opt/vertica/lib64/
DriverManagerEncoding = UTF-16
LogPath = /tmp
LogLevel = 4

-----------

ODBCINST.ini:
[dashboard]
Driver    = /opt/vertica/lib64/libverticaodbc.so.6.0.1
Description = Vertica test instance
Threading=0
FileUsage=1
DontDLClose=1

Comment: the above odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini is working with odbc_connect but not with pdo

Answer (score 1):

Most probably it is looking for the ini files in the wrong place, do an strace on the php file, and see if it tries to access the ini files from the correct path

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing

```
DRIVER={SOURCENAME};
```

to

```
Driver=Vertica
```

?